# FB.api not returning the username

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to get the username for a particular user by giving the user id as a param to the FB.api method. But it just returns undefined. If i console.log within the FB.api method, i can see the result. Unable to figure out.

```
var something;
var friendName = FB.api('/{{ user id }}', function(give){ something = give.name; });
console.log(something);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If i console.log within the FB.api method, i can see the result.

The method is *asynchronous*, that means the answer to the server-side call is not yet there when your following line (logging to console) is carried out – and therefor the callback function has not been executed yet, so it hasn’t set the var *something* at that point.

You should familiarize yourself with the basics of asynchronous execution in javascript!

Comment: so how do i make sure something has been executed upon?

Comment: You wrap whatever you want to have executed inside the callback function. Let me repeat: __You should familiarize yourself with the basics of asynchronous execution in javascript!__

Comment: @CBroe you sound just like my supervisor...although you didn't include "Period." at the end of your boldface sentence. Could you have helped amit by guiding to a path to help him improve? Yes. But did you? No. Great Help your answer but attitude, my Lord, has trodden many in their paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this php code instead

```
        <?php
        $username=$facebook->api('/user_id?fields=username');
        //with appropriate access tokens
        ?>
```

Comment: Stop indenting every line of your posts. Indenting is for rendering code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `console.log` inside the `callback` function.